# Choosing the right data structure

Tags: c++, sorting, stl

I have a Tool struct that contains information about a tool retrieved from a database table, where at program start up all tools are retrieved.

```
struct Tool {
    const int            id;
    const std::string    name;
    const std::string    category;
    int                  outcomeID;
}
```

And I have a ToolManager class that maintains these Tools in a vector for now. What I'm struggling with is what container is best for storing these based on how I need to retrieve and display them.

Sometimes they need to be displayed in a table grouping tools by their outcomeID. Many times they are displayed in a tree structure by category and by only one or two outcomeID's like so:

```
CategoryName1
    Tool_1
    Tool_3
CategoryName2
    Tool_5
```

I would rather **not** use Boost::multi_index (too complex for the nature of the project).
What is a simple, efficient way to store and retrieve these?

EDIT: To be clear, I need to be able store and look up these Tools by a combination of category or outcomeID.

Comment: Is it OK to maintain additional indexes manually in separate data structures?

Comment: @KerrekSB Yes it is OK. Just not sure how I should do that.

Comment: I guess this must be homework since why else would you extract data from a database and then re-implement the functionality of a database to view the data? e.g. `select * from Tools where category=="something" or outcomeID==someid`

Comment: @Skizz This is not homework if it was I would have tagged it. I figured it would be a better design if I retrieved all the tools at once and stored them in a virtual table to avoid unnecessary sql overhead. There is only at most 40 tools. There's no need to reload all the tools from the database every time I need to display the same information in a different way. If what I'm asking cannot be done simply just say so.

Comment: @rem45acp: Yes, there's an overhead to using SQL, but it does give you almost limitless ways to filter and sort the data. To re-implement all that would take a long time. It can be done, but why give yourself the extra work (and all the testing that goes with it)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to have a container with permanent iterators (such as `list`) as your main storage, and auxiliary containers of iterators for fast retrieval:

```
#include <list>
#include <set>

typedef std::list<Tool> container_type;
typedef container_type::iterator iterator_type;

struct outcome_cmp
{
    bool operator<(iterator_type const & a, iterator_type const & b) const
    {
        return a->outcomeID < b->outcomeID;
    }
};

container_type tools;
std::multi_set<iterator_type, outcome_cmp> outcome_index;

// insert "x":
auto it = tools.insert(tools.end(), x);
outcome_index.insert(it);
```

Now you can use the usual multiset iteration pattern to get the tools grouped by outcome ID.

Similarly, you can make an ordering for category and name:

```
#include <tuple>  // for std::tie and free lexicographic ordering

struct cat_cmp
{
    bool operator<(iterator_type const & a, iterator_type const & b) const
    {
        return std::tie(a->category, a->name) < std::tie(b->category, b->name);
    }
};

std::multiset<iterator_type, cat_cmp> cat_index;
```

Comment: What if I need to get all the tools that have a specific category and outcome?

Comment: So for category, name, and outcome it would simply be `std::tie(a->category, a->outcomeID, a->name)`. Nice.

Comment: @rem45acp: If you need actual *lookup* rather than just ordering, you could also have a `std::multimap<std::string, iterator_type, some_suitable_comparator>`.

Comment: I do need actual lookup but multimap does not offer look up by more than one key. Sometimes I need tools just be outcome, sometimes by a combination of others. I just can't involve boost::multi_index in this.